# Converting number into 32 bits in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, 32-bit

I have 32 bit numbers `A=0x0000000A` and `B=0X00000005`.

I get A xor B by `A^B` and it gives 0b1111.

I rotated this and got `D=0b111100000` but I want this to be 32 bit number not just for printing but I need MSB bits even though there are 0 in this case for further manipulation.

Comment: "I need MSB bits even though there are 0 in this case for further manipulation": What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

Most high-level languages don't have ROR/ROL operators. There are two ways to deal with this: one is to add an external library like ctypes or https://github.com/scott-griffiths/bitstring, that have native support for rotate or bitslice support for integers (which is pretty easy to add).

One thing to keep in mind is that Python is 'infinite' precision - those MSBs are always 0 for positive numbers, 1 for negative numbers; python stores as many digits as it needs to hold up to the highest magnitude difference from the default. This is one reason you see weird notation in python like ~(0x3) is shown as -0x4, which is equivalent in two's complement notation, rather than the equivalent positive value, but -0x4 is *always* true, even if you AND it against a 5000 bit number, it will just mask off the bottom two bits.

Or, you can just do yourself, the way we all used to, and how the hardware actually does it:

```
def rotate_left(number, rotatebits, numbits=32):
    newnumber = (number << rotatebits) & ~((1<<numbits)-1)       
    newnumber |= (number & ~((1<<rotatebits)-1)) << rotatebits
    return newnumber
```

Comment: Hey I got the rotating part covered. Thanks. I have number 0b111100000 but i want this in 32 bits I have to use 24th bit and 32nd bit which is 0 in this case and do some operations

Comment: Printing all 32 bits might require some extra work. But bits 24 and 31 actually exist; you can still get to them with e.g. `(number & (1<<24)) != 0`.

Comment: Okay I get it what you are saying. But look at my problem. I have got say D=0b111100000 which is printed as 480. Now This no. D is actually 32 bit. I want to xor 24th,0th and 32nd bit of this number and replace the MSB of D with the this bit and get a new number E. I was able to access those bits as you said but I couldn't replace the result into MSB

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'replace the result into MSB' - but you should be able to do e.g. `number |= 0x80000000` and see bit 31 set.

Answer (score 0):

To get the binary of an integer you could use [bin()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin).

Just an short example:

```
>>> i = 333333
>>> print (i)
333333
>>> print (bin(i))
0b1010001011000010101
>>>
```

Comment: I think you meant `bin()` not `bit()`

Comment: Oh... bad typo. Fixed + Thx.

Comment: Hey I did that but say A xor B comes out to be decimal 15 I get bin(ANSWER) it gives me 0b1111 but I would like to have0b00000000000000000000000000001111

Answer (score 0):

```
bin(i)[2:].zfill(32)
```

I guess does what you want.

I think your bigger problem here is that you are misunderstanding the difference between a number and its representation

```
12 ^ 18  #would xor the values
56 & 11  # and the values
```

if you need actual 32bit signed integers you can use numpy

```
a =numpy.array(range(100),dtype=np.int32)
```

Comment: Okay I get it what you are saying. But look at my problem. I have got say D=0b111100000 which is printed as 480. Now This no D is actually 32 bit. I want to xor 24th,0th and 32nd bit of this number and replace the MSB of D with the this bit and get a new number E.  Like Corley said I was able to access those bits but I couldnt replace the result into MSB